# pandas rolling how to retain the first time index of each time window

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Sorry for all the confusion I have made. `shift` method works perfectly fine. It turns out that `rolling` actually keeps all indices and all we have to do is to shift back, no matter if the indices are regular or not.

---

It seems that the pandas `rolling` method always keeps the *last* index of each time window. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['a', 'b'], index=pd.date_range('20170101', periods=10))
rolling_spearmanr = df['a'].rank().rolling(window=3).corr(other=df['b'].rank())

print(rolling_spearmanr)
```

Output:

```
2017-01-01         NaN
2017-01-02         NaN
2017-01-03    0.654654
2017-01-04   -0.596040
2017-01-05    0.277350
2017-01-06    0.466321
2017-01-07    0.429838
2017-01-08   -0.921551
2017-01-09   -0.188982
2017-01-10   -0.277350
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

What I want, though, is **a method that lets each time window keep its *first* index**. Is it possible?

---

Note that simply shifting the time index axis won't help, because time windows may not be regular (even though they have the same number of indices). E.g., when time index is *business* days instead of consecutive calendar days:

```
Index([2007-01-04, 2007-01-05, 2007-01-08, 2007-01-09, 2007-01-10, 2007-01-11], dtype='object', name='date')
```

Now if we perform `rolling` with `window=3`, what I want is something like

```
2017-01-04 ...
2017-01-09 ...
```

With the tradition `rolling method`, it will be

```
2017-01-08 ...
2017-01-11 ...
```

As you can see, if you simply shift the output dates back by `2` (since each time window is 3 indices long), you will *not* get the desired dates.

Comment: @Bharathshetty as i said, for example if index is `[2007-01-04, 2007-01-05, 2007-01-08, 2007-01-09, 2007-01-10, 2007-01-11]` and time window is `3`, then I want the output to have index `['2017-01-04', '2017-01-09']`, after dropping nan.

Comment: I dont think index is being considered at all  in rolling function

Comment: @Bharathshetty but `rolling` does keep the last index in each time window.

Comment: why you can not reversed the data frame and using the same method ?
`df.iloc[::-1]`

Comment: Can you add that code? I mean the traditional rolling method you said

Comment: @Wen the one you did quite recently

Comment: @Bharathshetty he mentioned there is duplicated index, so using `df.iloc[::-1]` is more safe than using `sort_values`

Comment: No hes saying something different. OP is talking about keeping the last index and first index . Im not sure how?

Comment: @Bharathshetty rolling will keep all index that is what rolling def for dude...

Comment: @Bharathshetty sorry for being unclear. Im not saying duplicate indexes, just how to keep the first. I'll try to add that "traditional method" later (which is in fact just the usual rolling method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Idea 1**
Hack by reversing the dataframe first, then back again...

```
(lambda d: d.a.rank().rolling(3).corr(d.b.rank()).iloc[::-1])(df.iloc[::-1])

2017-01-01    0.891042
2017-01-02    0.838628
2017-01-03    0.960769
2017-01-04   -0.897918
2017-01-05   -0.996616
2017-01-06    0.327327
2017-01-07    0.443533
2017-01-08   -0.178538
2017-01-09         NaN
2017-01-10         NaN
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

---

**Idea 2**

Use `pd.Series.shift`

```
rolling_spearmanr.shift(-2)

2017-01-01    0.891042
2017-01-02    0.838628
2017-01-03    0.960769
2017-01-04   -0.897918
2017-01-05   -0.996616
2017-01-06    0.327327
2017-01-07    0.443533
2017-01-08   -0.178538
2017-01-09         NaN
2017-01-10         NaN
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Im struggling from understanding what Op wants. Highly unclear

Comment: When using `pd.Series.rolling`, the aggregated value gets attached to the last index in the window.  OP is asking how to attach it to the first index instead.

Comment: @Bharathshetty sorry for the confusion I have caused.. I was thinking that `rolling` would work in "jumps" rather than consecutively. It turned out to be a stupid mistake.

Comment: @piRSquared you know me and wen also used this kind of method earlier I was confused by looking at the output index. I thought it was the output Op wanted.